# Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading

Tags: angular

I am trying to integrate an angular 2 application in an existed php
    application.
 but after i put it in the folder i receive this error.

> angular2-polyfills.js:390 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found)
>   loading main.js

```
 <script>
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript', 
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
    paths: {
      'app/*': 'consultation/scripts/*'
    },
    packages: {   
      "/angular2": {"defaultExtension": false},

      './app': {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      '@angular2-material/core': {
       format: 'cjs',
       defaultExtension: 'js',
       main: 'core.js'
     },
      '@angular2-material/checkbox': {
       format: 'cjs',
       defaultExtension: 'js',
       main: 'checkbox.js'
     },
      '@angular2-material/button': {
       format: 'cjs',
       defaultExtension: 'js',
       main: 'button.js'
     },
      '@angular2-material/radio': {
       defaultExtension: 'js',
       main: 'radio.js'
     },

      'ag-grid-ng2': {},
      'ag-grid': {},
      'ng2-select': {},
      'rxjs': {},
      'moment': {
              main: 'moment.js',
              type: 'cjs',
              defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
      'ng2-bootstrap': {"defaultExtension": "js"}
    },
    map: {  

            'moment': 'node_modules/moment',
            'ag-grid-ng2': 'node_modules/ag-grid-ng2',
            'ag-grid': 'node_modules/ag-grid',
            'ng2-select': 'node_modules/ng2-select',
            'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap',
            'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
            '@angular2-material/core': 'node_modules/@angular2-material/core/core',
            '@angular2-material/checkbox': 'node_modules/@angular2-material/checkbox/checkbox',
            '@angular2-material/button': 'node_modules/@angular2-material/button',
            '@angular2-material/radio': 'node_modules/@angular2-material/radio',
    }
  });
   System.defaultJSExtensions = true;
  System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to provide the SystemJS configuration to make us able to help you.

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: I would worry about the `System is not defined` error. To invistigate it properly, please add the full index.html contents to your question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image: picture of console output]You could try to update the `app` entry in the `packages` block like this:

```
map: {
  'app': 'consultation/scripts' // <-----
  (...)
},
packages: {
  "/angular2": {"defaultExtension": false},
  'app': { // <------
    format: 'register',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  (...)
}
```

Comment: it is always the same error i didn't understand what is the problem, do you think that i need to configure the router?

Comment: Which URL SystemJS tries to load?

Comment: i added the console msg

Comment: Your `paths` configuration isn't taken into account. I'd move it into the `map` block... I updated my answer.

Comment: it's always the same problem i did all the changes

Comment: Always the same URL is used by SystemJS?

Comment: yes but it takes into account what i did in the app map because if i change the path it will change it .

Comment: and it's not a path that can be resolved / corresponds to the js file of your module?

Comment: i expand the error maybe it will brings you other inoformation